# Mod_Rewrite - If no referrer detected then do rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

How can I apply a rule with mod_rewrite only if a file is directly accessed? (No referrer is detected)

I have this so far but it does not seem to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to match an empty string, [it's better to use the equality operator than a regex](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond). So, whilst [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo)'s answer will work, it would be better to use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=""
```

Answer (score 0):

As `.*` matches anything (even the empty string), this condition will never be fulfilled. Either use `!^(.+)` or simply `^$`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
```